# PHPBB: Email Notification on new post not working

Tags: php, email, phpbb, phpbb3

I am new to PHPBB. I have to setup email notification on new post arrives. I googled it and find BoardWatch is the best option for that. I have installed BoardWatch and followed this post https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/view-install/id_54328.

I have tried Mass email for testing any bugs in email configuration. But Mass email is working.
And Some people says There is one option in User Control panel -> Board Preference-> Edit Post Notification Options. But I got `"You have no post notification options available "`

Please provide me best way to trigger email notification when new post arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got solution.
Goto Admin Control Panel-> Email Settings

```
E-mail package size:0
This is the number of maximum e-mails sent out in one package. This setting is applied to the internal message queue; set this value to 0 if you have problems with non-delivered notification e-mails.
```

Comment: Do note that if you do not click the link in the notification email the board will no longer send you notifications.